# Java loop through each unique value

Tags: java, loops, csv, unique, divide

I have a csv file like this:

```
"user1","track1","player1"
-------------------------
"user1","track2","player2"
-------------------------
"user1","track3","player3"
-------------------------
"user1","track4","player4"
-------------------------
"user2","track2","player3"
-------------------------
.
.
"userN","trackM","playerX"
```

What I need to do is to divid tracks and players related to each user into a half and put them in separate files.
For example, for user1, if it has 4 lines, I need to divid it into two parts (the first two lines in file A, and the rest in file B), and repeating the same action for all users. 
This is what I wrote so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception { 

    BufferedReader userlines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/mona/Documents/Bolzano/Datasets/Lastfm_Matthias/lastfm_usertrackplayer.csv"));       
    String uLine = null;

    while ((uLine = userlines.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] userId = uLine.split(","); 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();       
        list.add(uLine);

    for(int i=0; i<=list.size();i++){       
    //  --> THIS FOR CONDITION IS MY PROBLEM,I need s.th like for(i=0; i<=(last unique userId (i.e., length of userId[i]) until it reaches the next unique userId)      
          //Divide the lines and put into two separate files           

            }
    }
    userlines.close();
}
```

Sorry I know it should be something simple, but I really could not find any related/similar question by googling my problem :(
Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: yes, they are separated by ","

Comment: You should first create a class containg these attributes, then read all the lines. Then next got through all the constructed instances and do some processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know "a priori" the number of lines for each user.
So you must memorize (in a List for example) all lines for the current user until you read the next user. Then save, in both files, the content of the list.

Clean the list, do the same thing for the next user.

**EDIT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception { 

    try(BufferedReader userlines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/mona/Documents/Bolzano/Datasets/Lastfm_Matthias/lastfm_usertrackplayer.csv"));) {       
    String uLine = null;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
    String currentUserId = null;     
    while ((uLine = userlines.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] userData = uLine.split(","); 
        String userId = userData[0]; // <-- get User ID here
        if (userId.equals(currentUserId)) {
            // Do what ever you need while buffering same userId
        } else {
            // Save currentUserId in file
            yourSaveMethod(list);
            currentUserId = userId;
            list.clear();
        }
        list.add(uLine);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually my problem is that I don't know how could I define unique users. (so then I could save the content related to each of them and save them ..)

Comment: I edited my code a little bit.. but still the problem is that the list that I defined, store each line.. so how can I reach the next unique userId?? I mean how it could recognize that it reached the next unique userId???

Comment: The userId is the first field, right ? So get it from the split result.

Comment: yes, I have already got it (in this line : `String[] userId = uLine.split(","); `), but I don't know how to write a condition so it understand when it reach to the NEXT userId...

Comment: Thanks for your great help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) `class` for parsing data.

**Example:**

```
    String str = "user1, track1, player1";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

    System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to count the number of lines for each unique userId (for example in my example user1 had 4 lines, so count=4), so I would be able to divide the lines into two parts... I was wondering if I could user this tokenizer to recognize the number of lines (e.g, whenever in the string there is space means another line), but I don't know how to do it

Comment: yes you can count number of line using tokenizer while putting separator as "\n". it will recognize '\n' as new line.